# How to retrieve data from Algolia with Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, full-text-search, algolia

I am using Firestore for my Android App. After designed my app and after adding all the filters now I want to implement full-text search in my app. I used Firebase functions to add the data of firestore to Algolia. I successfully integrate the data of Firestore and Algolia. Now I want to develop front-end for my application. For that I refer documentation from Algolia site. They have separate SDK for Android platform. But if I implement the same then I have to retrieve whole data from Algolia. Now I have already did all the filtering and query requests from the Firestore. So it will be very difficult for me to query the whole data from Algolia and not using Firestore query anywhere in my app. It will also be very costly for me as cost for requesting data from Algolia is very high. Is there any other way that I can still work with Firestore query and Filtering and when any user click on Search icon only then service of Algolia will be in use. 
I know it can sound something weird but reality is even I don't know what I want to ask here exactly. 
In simple sense is there any way that I can search in Firestore data through Algolia and then retrieve the data from firestore.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible. One solution is that you only store searchable attributes of an object in Algolia and store the whole object in firestore. You should use the objectID in Algolia as the document id in firestore so that you can directly query it in Firestore after receiving search results from Algolia in your client-side.

You can add another cloud function so that whenever a document changes, you also update the corresponding object in Algolia.